# how can i get the headers request from client side for sockets using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, sockets, header

I am quite new to this thing. I just wanted to know if it is possible to get the web sockets client side request header . By this i mean the header from client side for handshake .
Thank You in advance !
Sorry if the questio which i asked is not clear
What i want is to get a header format like this :

```
GET ws://websocket.example.com/ HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://example.com
Connection: Upgrade
Host: websocket.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
```

Comment: Quick clarification, you want to get something like this? `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.36 Safari/537.36 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see: [apache_request_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php)

```
<?php
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
?>
```

When you not run php as an apache module, you can use the [predefined `$_SERVER` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php):

```
foreach ($_SERVER as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
```

The above should return something like that shown below:

```
HTTP_HOST: testdrive 
HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive 
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: max-age=0 
HTTP_ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 
HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36 
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip,deflate,sdch 
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: nl,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6 
HTTP_COOKIE: __atuvc=1%7C8
```